# how do you size the plot in knitr pdf output

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, knitr

I am trying to use knitr to publish some ggplot output to pdf file.

the command that I am using is this:

````
```{r, results = 'asis', echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE,tidy=FALSE}
    ggplot(data,aes(datetime, usedmem, group=machine, colour=machine))+geom_line()+
        geom_smooth(method="lm", se=T, colour="blue")+
        facet_wrap(~machine)+theme_bw()
```
````

1. is it possible to set the size of the whole plot size. If there are bunch of servers in the data frame, the each plot within facet_wrap shrinks.
2. I see one chart per page, how would I print charts one after anther without wasting any space?

Comment: Please start with reading about and playing around with the [chunk options](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/#chunk_options) `fig.width`, `fig.height`, `out.width`, `out.height`. Regarding you second question you should consider writing `Rnw` instead of `rmarkdown` because this simplifies controlling the final PDF. If this is not an option or doesn't help please extend your example to something reproducible that generates "charts that waste space".

Answer (score 0):

To speak to your second question, try using the multiplot function found [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_%28ggplot2%29/). Like user2706569 said in the comment, this would require using knitr (just save your .rmw file as .Rnw) and adding in the following code. You can then call multiplot in whatever chunk you are using to generate the plots.

```
<<loadfunctions>>=

multiplot <- function(..., plotlist=NULL, file, cols=1, layout=NULL) {
  require(grid)
  plots <- c(list(...), plotlist)
  numPlots = length(plots)
  if (is.null(layout)) {
    layout <- matrix(seq(1, cols * ceiling(numPlots/cols)), ncol = cols, nrow = ceiling(numPlots/cols))
  }
 if (numPlots==1) {
    print(plots[[1]])
  } else {
    grid.newpage()
    pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(nrow(layout), ncol(layout))))
    for (i in 1:numPlots) {
      matchidx <- as.data.frame(which(layout == i, arr.ind = TRUE))
      print(plots[[i]], vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = matchidx$row, layout.pos.col = matchidx$col))
    }
  }
}
@


<<myplots, results='asis', fig.width=8, fig.height=6>>==
multiplot(someplot_1, someplot_2, cols = 2)

@
```

Answer (score 0):

Building a .Rnw file, as shown below, will help.  By tweaking the `out.width`, `fig.height`, and `fig.width` you can control the 'wasted space' issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Create several graphics
<<>>=
library(ggplot2)
plots <- lapply(unique(mpg$manufacturer),
                function(m) {
                  ggplot(mpg[mpg$manufacturer == m, ]) +
                  aes(x = model, y = cty) + 
                  geom_boxplot() +
                  ggtitle(m)
                })
@

<<echo = FALSE, results = "hide", out.width = "0.5\\textwidth">>=
plots
@

\end{document}
```